# Animating a UIButton's Text to Pinch In and Pinch Out Doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiviewanimation

So I have a `UIButton` that I want to change the text for with animations. The way the animation is *supposed* to work is the text of the button shrinks all the way down to nothingness, then the text changes, and then it scales back up to original size. I am still stuck at trying to get the text to shrink to nothingness correctly.

If I use this code:

```
 UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
        //Zzzeeeewwwwwwwwww
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.submitButton.titleLabel?.transform = self.submitButton.titleLabel!.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001);
        })


        //Wwwwwweeeeeeyyyyyppp
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.3, relativeDuration: 0.3, animations: {
               self.submitButton.titleLabel?.transform = self.submitButton.titleLabel!.transform.scaledBy(x: 100, y: 100);
        })
    }, completion: nil)
```

I only get animations for the first part, where it scales down correctly, but then does not scale back up. It just pops back into place without animating all the way as it grows back.

I tried by chaining `UIView` animations with durations ("the old fashioned way"), and the opposite happens. The first part happens instantly, then it grows back correctly. Here is the code for that:

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
        self.submitButton.titleLabel?.transform = self.submitButton.titleLabel!.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.01, y: 0.01);
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.submitButton.titleLabel?.transform = self.submitButton.titleLabel!.transform.scaledBy(x: 100, y: 100);
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have no idea what might be causing this issue. I've been stuck on this for hours. I haven't even gotten to the text changing yet. That causes a whole other range of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to note:

## 1. Scaling factors

In first scaling animation you specify `label.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001)`
But in the second: `label.transform.scaledBy(x: 100, y: 100)`

Note that you need to multiply by `1000` to get `1.0` in the end.

## 2. Relative keyframe time

The way adding keyframes works is by specifying relative time, which is in range `[0.0 - 1.0]`, so instead of `0.3` you need to specify `0.5` to get exactly one half of animation. Consider the following piece:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.001, y: 0.001)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: 1000, y: 1000)
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

If you abstract from labels, here's the animation you'll get
[image: animation]

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. But it worked!! It's so pretty!! (: Thanks